# Override order of resource bundles

Tags: java, jsf, bundle

How can I override the order that Java takes when searching for a label in the resource bundles?
Taken from the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/concept.html), the default order is this:

```
ButtonLabel_fr_CA_UNIX
ButtonLabel_fr_CA
ButtonLabel_fr
ButtonLabel_en_US
ButtonLabel_en
ButtonLabel
```

However I want to override this order by having variants taken first, like this:

```
ButtonLabel_fr_CA_UNIX
ButtonLabel_en_US_UNIX
ButtonLabel_fr_CA
ButtonLabel_fr
ButtonLabel_en_US
ButtonLabel_en
ButtonLabel
```

I defined a new class extending `ResourceBundle` class where you can set the parent bundle but I don't know when this class is being instantiated and what happens when I change the language in the `FacesContext`.
Is it possible to override the order somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to extend class `ResourceBundle.Control` and override method `getCandidateLocales` where you can specify the order of used locales.

Instance of this class is then passed to the `getBundle` method - I called this in the constructor of the class that extends `ResourceBundle` like this:

```
final Locale locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();
final CustomControl control = new CustomControl();
setParent(getBundle("MyBundle", locale, control));
```

This class can be used as `<resource-bundle>` in `faces-config.xml` or loaded with `<f:loadBundle ...>`

```
<resource-bundle>
    <base-name>com.package.MyBundle</base-name>
    <var>bundle</var>
</resource-bundle>
```